# Multi line regex with starting character and ending string

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches below conditions:

- 1st line should have only `}`. It may have an empty string at the beginning. But ends with `}` and a line break.
- 2nd line starts with `] at MyClass.MyMethod`
- There could be n number of lines here.
- Match should end when a line ending with `New Error Object: [` is encountered. This can be encountered in 2nd line itself too.

So, the below text should get two hits with the regex

```
  }
]   at MyClass.MyMethod
....
// Lines omitted for brevity
....
Exception: New Error Object: [
 {
   some json
 },
 {
   some more json
 }
]   at MyClass.MyMethod
....
// Lines omitted for brevity
....
Exception: New Error Object: [
```

Basically, I'm trying to stitch together multiple JSON arrays from a log file. Each JSON array is written with some log error message and I've to clean them up manually. I'm looking for a regex to match and replace it with a `,` to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
(?<=(^|\n)\s+}\n]   at MyClass.MyMethod)[\s\S]+?(?=New Error Object: \[(\n|$))
```

output with your example text:

```
....
// Lines omitted for brevity
....
Exception: 

....
// Lines omitted for brevity
....
Exception:
```